# Instancia en AWS no se detiene

Tags: aws

Me contrataron para trabajar sobre una instancia ya creada en AWS (ec2), pero el cliente y el anterior dev perdieron las keys, y para que pueda cambiarla hay un paso en donde tengo que apagar el servidor.

Mi problema viene cuando al tratar de apagarlo (ya sea desde awscli [incluso usando force] o desde la consola) no solo no se apaga, si no que se duplica, uno de los dos se borra (termina) y el otro empieza a correr automáticamente, y cuando lo intento lo mismo con la instancia que empezó a correr para exactamente lo mismo, cabe mencionar que solo pasa con esa instancia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más probable es que la instancia pertenezca a un grupo de autoescalado.

En los grupos de autoescalado, AWS garantiza que el número de instancias en ejecución estará siempre entre un valor mínimo y otro máximo definidos por el usuario.

Si la instancia está en un grupo de autoescalado con valor mínimo=1 y tu eliminas la instancia, AWS creará automáticamente una instancia nueva para mantener el equilibrio.

Una forma rápida de ver si la instancia pertenece a un grupo de autoescalado es consultar las etiquetas de la instancia. Si tiene una que dice `aws:autoscaling:groupName` entonces la instancia pertenece a un grupo de autoescalado.

Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es eliminar el grupo de autoescalado:

- Apunta el nombre del grupo de autoescalado (el valor asociado al tag que has visto antes). Apunta el id de la instancia para más seguridad
- En la consola de AWS accede al servicio EC2
- En el menú de la izquierda, abajo del todo, encontrarás el apartado *Auto Scaling*, selecciona "Auto Scaling Groups"
- Localiza el grupo de autoescalado
- Accede a la pestaña "Instances" del grupo de autoescalado y verifica que la instancia asociada al grupo se corresponde con la que has apuntado.
- Elimína el grupo de autoescalado